# Cypress Test Runner hides form labels

Tags: cypress

With "experimentalSourceRewriting": true in cypress.json I have observed that cypress test runner hides some form labels.

My html form is as below when rendered on a normal browser (screenshot 1)

```
<div class="cp_label"><label for="c_B2CC050B-DF0E-4CA2-8A0A-AE4A0036FABA" id="aria-label_c_B2CC050B-DF0E-4CA2-8A0A-AE4A0036FABA">Job Announcement Type <span class="cp_mStar">*<span style="position: absolute; clip:rect(1px 1px 1px 1px)"> Mandatory</span></span></label></div>
```

The Label "Job Announcement Type" is displayed correctly as seen in the Screenshot 1

And on Cypress Test Runner(Chrome) it is as below (screenshot 2)

```
<div class="cp_label"><label for="c_B2CC050B-DF0E-4CA2-8A0A-AE4A0036FABA" id="aria-label_c_B2CC050B-DF0E-4CA2-8A0A-AE4A0036FABA"><span class="cp_mStar">*<span style="position: absolute; clip:rect(1px 1px 1px 1px)"> Mandatory</span></span></label></div>
```

The Label "Job Announcement Type" is not displayed as seen in the Screenshot 2

If I disable "experimentalSourceRewriting" by setting it to false, the above form label is displayed correctly.

I need this setting to be true as cypress fails with a Whoops No tests error when I click on  a button that navigates to a different page (with in the same superdomain)

Are there ways I can get over this issue of fields getting hidden.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots are missing.

Comment: Can't reproduce it with that HTML fragment (experimentalSourceRewriting: true) - the label text shows up. Can you add the `select` HTML as well (the  element `for="c_B2CC050B-DF0E-4CA2-8A0A-AE4A0036FABA"` refers to).